# Elements of finite extension of fields that are fixed by embeddings into an algebraically closed field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

I'm having trouble with the following problem:

Let $E/F$ be a finite extension where $\operatorname{char}(F)=0$, and A be an algebraically closed field containing $E$. Prove that if $\alpha\in E$ such that $\sigma(\alpha)=\alpha$ for all embedding $\sigma:E\to A$ such that $\sigma|_F=\operatorname{id}_F$, then $\alpha\in F$.

My idea is to apply the primitive element theorem (due to the given conditions), say $E=F(\gamma)$ for some $\gamma\in E$. Then, $\alpha$ can be written in terms of $\gamma$. I'm not sure if this will be useful. I think the main issue is that I don't how to use the assumption that $A$ is algebraically closed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @AnneBauval characteristic zero is an essential assumption. In characteristic $p$ we have the counterexample where  $F = \mathbb{F}_p(t)$, $E = \mathbb{F}_p(t^{1/p})$, and $A$ is an algebraic closure thereof. Every $F$-embedding of $E$ into $A$ fixes $t^{1/p}$ but it is not an element of $F$.

Answer (score 2):

Over $A$, the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ splits as $\prod_\sigma (x-\sigma(\alpha))=(x-\alpha)^n=x - n \alpha x^{n-1} + \cdots$. Since this polynomial has coefficients in $F$, we have $n \alpha \in F$. Since $\operatorname{char}(F)=0$, we have $n\ne0$ and so $\alpha \in F$.

Comment: Could you please explain why the minimal polynomial splits as $\prod_\sigma(x-\sigma(\alpha))$? I understand that it splits into linear factors, but I don't understand how the factors relate to $\sigma$ (I'm assuming that the product extends over $F$-embedding $\sigma:E\to A$ as defined in the question). Thanks.

Comment: @LiangPrime, if $p \in F[x]$, then $f(\sigma(\alpha))=\sigma(f(\alpha))=0$. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_element_(field_theory)